# Triggering the popup of invalid input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have **successfully** checked whether an input is valid or invalid (empty or not in my case [please ignore the `susbtring()`, I have to use that because of a specific requirement]). **However,** I want to **manually** trigger the default popup saying `Input field is not valid` when you don't input anything in an `<input>` and you submit the form.

I would like to do the above because the target input I want to check valid or invalid is in a hidden 'tab'. If possible, I don't want a work-around solution. Is it possible to trigger that popup manually?

I checked whether the target input is valid or not using:

```js
trackedInput = $('#trackedInput');
confirmSubmit = $('#confirmSubmit');

confirmSubmit.click(function(e) {
    if (!trackedInput.val().substring(4)) {
        tabs.eq(0).trigger('click'); //tabs.eq(0) here selects the first div and 'click' it, causing it to be not_hidden and causing the current 'not_hidden' div to be hidden
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class = "hidden">
  <input id = "trackedInput" type = "text" form = "confirm">
</div>

<div class = "hidden">
  //Some other stuffs here
</div>

<div class = "not_hidden">
  <input id = "confirmSubmit" type = "submit" form = "confirm">
</div>

<form id = "confirm"></form>
```

**EDIT:**

By the default popup, I meant this: [the 'Please fill out this field' popup](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/214_html5_form_validation/tutorial/images/submission_error.png).

Comment: Could you show us the relevant HTML and JS code. Thanks.

Comment: @Ekown That is the relevant part, though. Could you tell me specifically what you are looking for? My `input` is, as mentioned, contained within a `div` that is hidden (`display: none`). My `input type = "submit"` is contained within a `div` that is **not** hidden.

Comment: The HTML code would be helpful. Furthermore, what do you mean by the 'default popup' ? Is it the default popup for the HTML input validation? Can you clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: @Ekown I've included the link to the popup in my original post.

Comment: @Ekown I've also provided the basic idea of my HTML code.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it now.

Comment: Could you also give the link of that particular tutorial? It seems that they overwrote the default popup.

Comment: @Ekown I want the default popup. I'm not using that tutorial, though, I only took its picture because it seems similar to mine. Wait, let me get the **exact** popup look I want (which is the default when you don't input a field and it's required and you submit, you can try it yourself too).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188391/discussion-between-ekown-and-richard-w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`form.reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) for that. It basically checks the form and validates it, and if it detects an invalid field, it will trigger that popup message.

```js
trackedInput = $('#trackedInput');
confirmSubmit = $('#confirmSubmit');
yourForm = document.querySelector('#confirm');

confirmSubmit.click(function(e) {
  if (!trackedInput.val().substring(4)) {
    yourForm.reportValidity();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <input id="trackedInput" type="text" form="confirm" required>
</div>

<div class="hidden">
  //Some other stuffs here
</div>

<div class="not_hidden">
  <input id="confirmSubmit" type="submit" form="confirm" required>
</div>

<form id="confirm"></form>
```